# Hide more than one element

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I have for example 2 `UIButton`

I know how to hide each one :

```
button1.hidden = 1;
button2.hidden = 1;
```

Is there any way to hide this 2 buttons in one time ? (eg : `[button1, button2].hidden = 1`)

Thanks

edit : any way is array style ?

eg :

```
array *buttons = [button1, button2 ...] ;   
buttons[0,3,5,10].hidden = 1;
```

Comment: Is that different to user with one line or two?

Comment: no, but I have a lot of button to set hidden or not ... so I'm looking for a tip to put this in an array and hide elements in one line.

Comment: put them on the same parent view , then hide the parent view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of buttons like:

```
NSArray *buttonsArray = @[bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4];
```

and an array of bool values corresponding to the button state:

```
NSArray *stateArray = [@YES,@NO,@NO,@YES];
```

Then you could:

```
for (UIButton *bt in buttonsArray){
   bt.hidden = [[stateArray objectAtIndex:[buttonsArray indexOfObject:bt]] boolValue];
}
```

or a more efficient one:

```
for(int index=0; index<buttonsArray.count; index++){
    [[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:index] setHidden:[[stateArray objectAtIndex:index] boolValue]];
}
```

or a more clean, readable one:

```
for(int index=0;index<buttonsArray.count; index++){
   UIButton *bt = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:index];
   BOOL *state = [[stateArray objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];
   bt.hidden=state;
}
```

The easiest would be (theoretically), a comment given by @adali , to add it to a parent view and then hide the parent view. But then you should create the parent view appropriately and set the parent views frame according to your UI. (Choose whichever is easier to you: i.e creating the buttons,state array etc or creating a parent view and positioning it properly)

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply use:

```
 for (UIButton *btn in [self.view subviews]) {
    btn.hidden = YES;
}
```

Or you can find the buttons by a condition:

```
 for (UIButton *btn in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([btn tag]<=2) {
        btn.hidden = YES;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to do it :

```
- (void)buttonAction
{
    for (UIButton *button in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if (button.hidden == YES)
             button.hidden = NO;
        else
             button.hidden = YES;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this

```
button1.hidden = button2.hidden = YES;
```

But if you can create a method which does this will help you, e.g.

```
- (void)allButtonHidden:(BOOL)value {
    button1.hidden = value;
    button2.hidden = value;
}
```

and call it

```
[self allButtonHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, and if button1.hidden = 0 and button2.hidden = 1 ?? any way to right like this : [button1, button2].hidden = [0,1] ?

Comment: `button1.hidden = !button2.hidden = YES;`

Comment: hehe ... yes but there is no way with array written style ? like array *buttons = [button1, button2 ...] ; buttons[0,3,5,10].hidden = 1 ... ?

Comment: Yeah there isn't any syntax that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's very tricky but according to your requirement, there is an alternative solution.

1) Set the tag for each button

```
[button1 setTag:1];
[button2 setTag:2];
...
...
```

2) Find the button object with tag (which you can run with the loop)

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfButton;i++)
{
    UIButton *targetButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    targetButton.hidden = 1;
}
```